# Look for documentation about how precisely modules parts are loaded (Drupal 7)

Tags: 7

Developping my custom module, I ran several times into misunderstood issues regarding the precise order used by Drupal when loading parts of a module.
Each time, I finally got rid of it after any disabled and suppressed then recreated, but this is obviously not satisfying.

So I'm now looking for sufficient information to be able to understand what happens in those circumstances.

This time the problem I have is as follows:

1. Having my module working fine on a site under D-7.34, I upgraded it to D-7.35, following all necessary steps.
2. After successfully executing update.php (which notified that no update was needed), I clicked to go to front page: this one was properly displayed.
   NOTE: **necessarily, my module was already involved at this stage**, since it works during output rendering (so whatever the path indicated by the URL)
3. But from there, then, any attempt to access another page (either public or administrative one) fires a PHP error "Call to undefined function *myfunction()*...", where *myfunction()* belongs to my module.

I can't figure out how it is possible, since my code schematically looks like:

**file: mymodule.module**

```
<?php

module_load_include('inc', 'mymodule', 'mymodule.core');

function mymodule_some_hook() {
    # ...
    myfunction();
    # ...
}
```

**file: mymodule.core**

```
<?php

function myfunction() {
    # ...
}
```

In other words, in my eyes:

- when the error fires, it necessarily means that *mymodule.module* was loaded, since it is where *myfunction()* call resides
- then if *mymodule.module* was loaded, it should have first executed *module_load_include()*, so loading *mymodule.core* and defining *myfunction()*

Yet it is clear that, in this case, something is happening differently!

But why this behaviour now, and not at the first access to front page?
And why this behaviour with D-7.35 (where no changes seem to be involved here), and not with D-7.34?

NOTE: I suspected something wrong with caching, so I tried flushing it. But flushing process failed with the same "Call to undefined function".
Then I used directly PhpMyAdmin to truncate all cache tables, without success: behaves the same after that.

Comments greatly welcome, and notably if pointing to any documentation about detailed process of modules load.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you employing a PHP opcode caching tool, like APC, on your server?

Comment: @ShawnConn: no, I don't. Nothing about documentation? TIA.

Comment: I don't know off-hand of a resource on d.o. I believe .module gets parsed when Drupal rebuilds its system module/theme cache. A simple solution to your problem is to add module_load_include inside your hook function.

Comment: @ShawnConn: great idea, so now it works! In the other hand, it doesn't seem right to have to do that, especially as I have a number of hooks invoking that function. And most of all because i keep wondering why my initial, global scoped, module_load_include() is not executed? Anyway, thanks for the tip.

Comment: I believe the solution there is to use files[] = definition in you .info file. I believe that makes the included file available in your module (not sure if global).

Comment: @ShawnConn: files[] definitions are already in my .info file. I included them early when developping my module, merely because the docs told it - but furtherly learned I had to call module_load_include() in spite of that. Not really sure what is necessary and what is enough. But for now I have file[] definitions PLUS module_load_include() in global scope PLUS module_load_include in function - really should work :-)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of tests, I'm now pretty convinced that, despite it is not mentioned in the [release notes](https://www.drupal.org/drupal-7.34-release-notes) page, a change happened in 7.34, which consists in that, now, the full-bootstrap condition is not reached yet when the MODULE.module file is loaded.

According to [module_load_include()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/7) page, this function **requires Drupal to be fully bootstrapped**: this clearly relies to the use of `drupal_get_path()` (see the function code in this page), which is not available without full-bootstrap.

It is why my (global-scoped) `module_load_include()` calls are executed but without result (see 'file: mymodule.module' in my question above).

I had to modify my module, including a dedicated `module_load_include()` call inside each function which needed it, like this:

```
<?php

function mymodule_some_hook() {
    module_load_include('inc', 'mymodule', 'mymodule.core');
    # ...
    myfunction();
    # ...
}
```

This way, now all works fine anew.

I verified it is the same with Drupal 7.36: my module doesn't work in its original implementation, then it does with this modification.

Hope this helps.