# require doesn't work in a module's file

Tags: 7

I have this module's inc file, which hold `page callback` functions. Also I have a 'config.php' file that hold the parameters. I know this is not a good practice, but I would like to leave these config there for now.

Here is the question, I cannot get access to the parameters in the config.php file after I used `require 'config.php'` or `require_once 'config.php'`.

e.g. I have admin.inc which holds these:

```
<?php
    require 'config.php';
    
    function my_page_callback(){
        global $config;

        var_dump($config); //this prints NULL when I access this menu item.
    }
```

and config.php holds these an located in the same folder:

```
<?php

    $config = array();
    $config['key'] = 'value';
    $config['name'] = 'foobar';
```

The file is successfully included since there is no fatal error, but why can't I get these values?

### update

`var_dump($config);` this would print the right content after I move the require statement to the body of `my_page_callback`, but I don't think this is how PHP works.

Explicitly set `$config` as global in the required file could give non-NULL result, but it is not needed in my test files.

Comment: That doesn't add up - a failed `require` will result in a fatal error, so printing NULL could never happen. Unless you mean you see a white screen? And yes, with the best will in the world, that's a shocking way to store your config variables given that Drupal has entire systems dedicated to it. You're even forcing yourself to use global vars. Highly recommend doing it the proper way, it'll save you headaches in the future. By the way, to fix, you probably just want `require __DIR__ . '/config.php';`, your current working directory will probably be the Drupal root

Comment: @Clive I am new to module development, so it will take some time to prepare a proper page used to set these variables which will never be changed, so I choose this quick and dirty way. But I still don't understand why this happen. It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: If they never change surely they can be defined as constants at the top of the module rather than including them in a separate file

Comment: I have tried `require __DIR__ . '/config.php';` , same result. I can use `file_get_contents( __DIR__ . '/config.php');` to show the content, but I can not access the variables.

Comment: In that case I'd say it's because you're missing a semi-colon at the end of the statement.

Comment: @ColinShipton Yep. I got this third-party API, and just to make a little bit change and try it out with drupal, but failed.

Comment: @Clive Sorry it's a typo. And I have tried to move the require statement to the body of the callback function, and this time it worked. It's so strange.

Comment: Oh, I've just noticed what you may be doing wrong - global vars in `require`d files might need to be explicitly set to global to be used in the requesting file, e.g. `global $config = array();`. Can't remember if that's a thing (might used to have been in an older version of PHP or something). You're working with stuff that people try to avoid at all costs, so help will be limited :)

Comment: @Clive Really? I don't think that's the problem.  I have tried this with two simple files, and it works fine although the variable in the required file is not   `global`. Is it possible that Drupal did some tricks with those require statements?

Comment: No not possible, Drupal runs on top of the language, it doesn't have the capacity to alter it in any way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25808/discussion-between-leetom-and-clive).

Comment: Can't chat at the moment...I would continue to play with non-Drupal versions of the code until you get that working in the same way you want to use it in Drupal (i.e. a function trying to use a global that's defined in a required file). Once you have that working outside of Drupal, it's guaranteed to work inside of Drupal

Comment: @Clive Explicitly set `$config` as global in the `require`d file did work, but it is not needed in my test files.

Comment: I already experienced such a strange behaviour. In my case I was using the regular Drupal `module_load_include()` function instead of `require` but the result was the same: all worked fine if located in the function body, but ignored if at the file root. **This behaviour appeared only as of 7-35**. My guess is that Drupal might analyze your file to extract functions code, then cache them and `eval()` them when needed. So I had to insert an include invocation in each of the tunctions that need the included contents, and so it works fine now.

Comment: @cFreed Drupal definitely doesn't do anything like that. I have Drupal 7.38 sites working fine with `require_once` at the top of module files; it's just very basic PHP, not something Drupal could (or would want to) mess with. Files are included and executed, never cached and eval'd. This has to be something you guys are doing differently, server config, something like that. Just as an aside,  `module_load_include()` isn't supposed to be used in the global scope as it's not reliable during the installation phase of a bootstrap. That's why `require` with `__DIR__` should be used every time

Comment: Indeed @cFreed and leetom, this is the expected behaviour **from PHP itself**. Not related to Drupal. See [Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002188), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10647992/accessing-global-variables-in-a-separate-php-script), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973664/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-scope-of-require-once-explicitly-to-global) and dozens of others. The solution is to use the language as it's been designed: declare global vars as global: `global $config = array();`

Comment: @Clive. You're right: I'd incorrectly remembered the exact context of [my issue](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/154002/look-for-documentation-about-how-precisely-modules-parts-are-loaded-drupal-7), where the problem was that the behaviour of `module_load_include()` changed as of 7-35, just like you pointed out.

Comment: @Clive _Using global keyword outside a function is not an error. It can be used if the file is included from **inside** a function._ According to those links, `global` is not needed when declare the variable, and  `global $config = array();` generates a syntax error!

Comment: @leetom don't have time to go into a full explanation (sick baby being quite demanding!), all I can tell you is that this is s language issue, and couldn't possibly be anything that Drupal's doing differently - PHP is PHP, and those parts of the language simply can't be augmented at run time. They can with a suitable extension to PHP itself, but not via the language, and definitely not on-the-fly - it just isn't a "thing"

Comment: @Clive I found the reason in the link provided by Nick. The reason is that Drupal include these module files in a function, then I have to declare those    variables as globals before initialize them. Thank you for your patients :)

Comment: Yes, that'll be it! Very happy the bottom of that has been gotten to :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd comment on sceo's answer, but I can't yet.

More information on declaring it as global $var: https://www.drupal.org/node/633230#comment-2267370

But as is recommended here, in the link and everywhere really, if you want globals use variable_set and variable_get (or use constants? You can serialize the array, as constants before PHP 5.6 can't accept arrays).

You can also make a function in your module file that simply returns the array you want to use. Not sure how correct or efficient that is, but it does work.

```
function mymodule_get_config() {
    return array(
      'key' => 'value'
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information provided in the link, this answered my question! hmm, already answered 6 years ago :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach to include a file in .module

```
function module_name_init(){
    module_load_include('inc', 'module_name', 'includes/common');
}
```

and place common.inc file in includes folder in your custom module.Now write your php code here.

Comment: Thank you, this is a good solution. But I am still curious about the strange behaviour here.

Answer (score 0):

Agree that this is bad practice and you should be setting these values using variable_set and variable_get, or with a module config form.

However, it should work the way you have it with the exception that you will need to 'global $config' in the config.php file AND then again in my_page_callback().

You would do better to rename $config to something more specific, so you don't have collisions with anything else in the global scope, so change $config in config.php to something like $my_module_config or something.

Comment: I have some prefix in the variable names, those lines are just mockup of hundreds lines of codes. Could you provide a link that says _need to 'global $config' in the config.php file AND then again in my_page_callback()._? I don't see any clue about this, and ` global $config = array()` will generate a syntax error.